# Windows Phone Self Signed SSL Certificates

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, ssl-certificate

I have been trying to Install Self Signed Certificates on windows phone, with format *.jks certificates given to me by the server person , steps i did
1. Created Email account on the Windows Phone Emulator.
2. Email with certificate as attachment sent to the Emulator Configured Email Account.
3. When i try to Click on the Attachment ( which is a certificate with *.jks extn) , it fails to recognize and pops up a message " you need to install App for this task, would you like to search one in store".
4. When i click "Yes" , results are "no app found".

now Questions,
1. What am i doing Wrong?.
2. Is there certain Certificates format that are supported on Windows Phone.
3. What are my alternatives.

Comment: JKS format is for Java only, Windows knows nothing about it. You need to convert your certificate store most likely to PFX format (if you have a self-signed certificate with a private key in JKS). Doing this is a different question which should be asked separately.

Comment: Hi, I'm very interested by your topic :) . We can auto-sign windows phone 8 application? When I was on Nokia training days, trainer say for entreprise, we can create a private "marketplace" and auto-sign the application. But I never found explain on the net... Have you more information about that? By Advance Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DocRoms I guess this is what your looking http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidhardin/archive/2010/12/30/wp7-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates.aspx